# Where can I find free source code online to learn Unit testing on

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have started this course on Pluralsight about  testing .Net application(desktop application, WinForms) with NUnit because I want to learn how to test code(I am a tester). 
The project I work on now has a huge application and the source code is too complicated for me right now.
Where can I find the source code for a desktop application(open source I guess) so I can start learning how to unit test by referencing that code to my test project in Visual Studio. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a Microsoft-maintained list of open source .NET developer projects](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/dotnet-developer-projects.md). Alternatively, they also have a list of [consumer projects](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/dotnet-consumer-projects.md) (which perhaps may be easier to sink your teeth into).

If none of those suit your fancy, [GitHub has about a million .NET projects for you to explore](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=.net&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).